# Accessing JavaScript file in HTML through parent level directories on an HTTP server

Tags: javascript, html, path, parent, filepath

I'm trying to access hellotest.js, which is located in the parent directory of my index2.html file.
I'm having no luck doing this, the fix should be simple and I have tried looking for an answer.
The absolute path to the files are (Ubuntu/Linux):
/home/petrus/dev/testbeds/http-server/index2.html
/home/petrus/dev/testbeds/hellotest.js

EDIT: I'm running this on an http-server: [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="../hellotest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <title>test website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>hello world 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't worry about why I'm trying to do this, I'll be accessing a file 3 directories up and 4 directories down once I get this to work.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Are you using a web server or just loading the page into the browser?

Comment: I'm using http-server: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server  
Also tried with SimpleHttpServer: https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html

Comment: Maybe you can't access it because the base directory of your http-server is `/home/petrus/dev/testbeds/http-server`, so for security reasons, it forbid the access to anything outside that base directory.

What error do you get?

Comment: You're right, I'm getting:  
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///home/petrus/dev/testbeds/hellotest.js  
Saw this now that I changed it to an absolute path.

Comment: Write an answer and I'll approve it.  
Is there any way to access files located elsewhere?  
I'll try using symlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this problem eventually by creating symlinks.
In Linux/Ubuntu you can do this with: `ln -s <symlink_origin> <symlink_destination`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using .. to navigate up to the parent directory just use the directory name. Try testbeds/hellotest.js.

Comment: No luck, tried that and even putting in the absolute path.
Also tried with the absolute path, like so: `file:///home/petrus/dev/testbeds/hellotest.js`